# How can I get video with audio in twilio while video calling

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twilio

I am using Twilio programmable video to implement video calling feature in our existing application. We need to record the video while calling. In Twilio both audio and video files are saved. Now I have to play same video in my application.

Is there any way to get video with audio both together from twilio?
or Is there any component which can utilize both together?
I need to implement this from my frontend (react) application.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio does not provide the video and the audio in the same file, all recordings are single track.

You could download and [combine the audio and video together, using something like ffmpeg](https://davidwalsh.name/combine-audio-video).

Alternatively, you can load the audio into an `<audio>` element and the video into a `<video>` element then implement controls that play/pause both elements at the same time.

Let me know if that helps at all.

**EDIT**

Now available: the [Video Recording Composition API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/compositions-resource) allows you to compose the various audio and video files produced from a room recording. Check out the [blog post announcement for more details](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/05/group-room-video-compositions-api.html).

Comment: Who needs separate audio and video?

Comment: You might just want the audio if you want to run it through a audio transcription service. However, there is now a way to get both without merging it yourself. Check out the [Video Recording Composition API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/compositions-resource) for all the ways you can combine the multitude of video and audio files that a video chat can create.

Comment: I will check it now. Thanks.